# Java interrupt inputstream without close() method

Tags: java, apache, http, iostream

So, I have a piece of code which connects to a Server and downloads about 2gb of content in 2mb chunks. All this is done in a Thread. Sometimes I need to stop the Thread because different errors occured in the main Thread or I want to close the application. My problem is that I am not able to close the InputStream of the connection. Everytime I invoke the `close()` method the InputStream consumes the whole 2gb send by the server. 
Is there a way to close an InputStream without consuming the whole content send over by the Server?

```
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(res.getEntity().getContent()), bytes_read, CHUNK_SIZE);
res.getEntity().getContent().close();
```

`res.getEntity().getContent()`returns the InputStream created from the connection.

`res` is an apache httpResponse.

`fos` is the FileOutputStream I want to save the response content to.

**Edit: Run method of thread**

CHUNK_SIZE: int: 2mb in bytes

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int expectedCode;
    do{
        try {
            client = HttpClients.createDefault();

            HttpGet req = new HttpGet(url.toString());
            HttpResponse res = client.execute(req);

            if (res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                while(running){
                    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(res.getEntity().getContent()), bytes_read, CHUNK_SIZE);
                }
            } else {
                log.error(Languages.getString("Download.2") + expectedCode); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex);
        } finally{
            try{
                rbc.close();
            } catch(Exception ex){
                log.error(ex);
            }
        }
    }while(!isFinished() && running);
    try{
        rbc.close();
        fos.close();
        client.close();
    } catch(Exception ex){
        log.error(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: So whenever you call .close(), the thread is blocked until all 2Gb of data has been tranfered ?

Comment: The .close() method blocks the Thread and receives untill all 2gb are read but it does not transfer any byte it only clears the inputstream

Comment: Maybe, .close() is not culprit, but the code around it. What is the actual implementation of InputStream ? Can you post some addition code around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying implementation of Apache HttpClient uses a ContentLengthInputStream for keeping the response. As mentioned in ContentLengthInputStream, the .close() method never actually close the stream, but read all remaining bytes until Content-Length is reached.

Solution: Instead of calling `res.getEntity().getContent().close()`, try `res.close()` or `req.abort()`